# Does Laravel have a convention for a local permanent uploaded file storage location?

Tags: laravel, file-upload, laravel-5, storage

I have some forms that allow the user to upload files that only they can view so I will have to store them somewhere. However, I haven't been able to find any information about where these files would usually be stored if I want them to be kept on the local server. Therefore I have to assume that there is no convention for the permanent storage location of uploaded files. Am I correct in this assumption?

To be clear, I'm not talking about temporary storage locations.

Additionally, would it be a bad idea to have the storage location of all the files as a subfolder of the app directory (with gitignore enabled on it)? Or would it be a better idea to have it outside of the app folder? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There is no explicit convention on where to store user uploaded files.**

---

However Laravel ships with a `storage` directory where it stores framework related data such as cache, sessions, etc. As the name denotes it's a good place to store files, not just framework files. Also the [Laravel Filesystem Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/filesystem#configuration) mentions that the default configured location is `storage/app` (but that can be changed to fit your needs):

> When using the local driver, note that all file operations are relative to the root directory defined in your configuration file. By default, this value is set to the storage/app directory. Therefore, the following method would store a file in `storage/app/file.txt`:  `Storage::disk('local')->put('file.txt', 'Contents');`

**This storage/app folder will by default be ignored by Git.**

If you also need the files to be publicly available, then you have two options:

**1.** Store them somewhere in the `public` directory.

**2.** Store them in the `storage` directory as suggested above and create a symbolic link to the folder from a `public` location. On Linux you can run this:

```
ln -s /path/to/laravel/public/files /path/to/laravel/storage/app/files
```

Of course the directory names can be whatever you like, I used `files` as an example.

The first option is for cases where you don't have shell access or are otherwise unable to create symbolic links. So if possible I suggest you use the second option.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel uploads to the temporary file path, then you will have to move the file:

`$request->file('photo')->move($destinationPath);`

This method will move the file from its temporary upload location (as determined by your PHP configuration) to a more permanent destination of your choosing.

**SOURCE:** https://laravel.com/docs/master/requests#files